# No compatible devices when uploading to Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I've been having problems when I upload my app to the Play store. It says "0 compatible devices". I don't know what's wrong as the APK compiles and works on many devices as I've tested it. Is there a way to fix this as people can't download my app?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.QbotIndustries.MoreMobs" >
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity
        android:name=".MainSplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
     />
     <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay" 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
     <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen" 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
     <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser" 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing your Android manifest file. If you have already published the app, the link to Google Play store could help as well.

Comment: Maybe u haven't published the apk yet? If you did check on the manifest as well as try to re-upload / republish it (remember to change the version in the manifest) Sometimes I've encountered that on google play, they don't recognize apk uploaded when your connection gets interrupted.

Comment: Share your Android Manifest code and you'll get the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you double check the "[uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)" and "[supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)" elements in your manifest file. They are used by the Play store to filter apps.